# MySQL Selecting multiple rows with the same joining ID from the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

MySQL database example:

```
data_name | page_id | data
--------------------------
brand | 83 | brandA
brand | 88 | brandA
brand | 89 | brandA *
type | 89 | typeA *
type | 90 | typeA
type | 98 | typeA
```

The only data I have going in is:

```
data_name = brand, 
data_name = type,
data = brandA,
data = typeA
```

What I need is the first page_id that is the same. So in this case, 89,89 are the same. So thats the result I want to return.

What I have that almost works is:

```
 SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE (`data_name` = 'brand' AND `data` = 'brandA') OR (`data_name` = 'type' AND `data` = 'typeA')
```

I could foreach the result in PHP, but I would prefer to find out the answer in MySQL.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: do you need result like this: brand | 89 | brandA *
type | 89 | typeA * ?

Comment: I just need the page_id. So I only need 89

Comment: I mean, you want to find duplicates of page_id?

Comment: Yes, I want to find the first duplicate of the page_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing here...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(data_name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,page_id  INT NOT NULL
,data VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(data_name,page_id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('brand',83,'brandA'),
('brand',88,'brandA'),
('brand',89,'brandA'),
('type',89,'typeA'),
('type',90,'typeA'),
('type',98,'typeA');

SELECT x.page_id 
  FROM my_table x 
 WHERE (data_name,data) IN(('brand','brandA'),('type','typeA')) 
 GROUP  
    BY page_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
+---------+
| page_id |
+---------+
|      89 |
+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked first time! Very neat. I really appreciate the help. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

in that case if you just want to display all the `ID` of your records that have a brand and value try this command it will display every `ID` you want that have already TYPE and BRAND

```
SELECT A.page_id
FROM data A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM data ) as B ON B.page_id = A.page_id AND B.data_name != A.data_name
GROUP BY A.page_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, joining the table onto itself:

```
SELECT
    d1.page_id
FROM
    (SELECT
        pade_id
    FROM
        `data`
    WHERE
        data_name = 'type') d1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        pade_id
    FROM
        `data`
    WHERE
        data_name = 'brand') d2
    ON d1.page_id = d2.page_id;
```

Comment: Just got to a computer to test. Slightly adjusted it to work.

Comment: What about brandA and typeA !?!

Comment: The example shows that is always the same, but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

should work:

```
SELECT orig.page_id, second.page_id as s_page_id 
FROM `data` as orig, (SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE page_id = orig.page_id AND  data_name = 'brand') AS second 
WHERE orig.data_name = 'type';
```

Comment: As written, `orig` is not available within the scope of the subquery